# How to allow just data from an array into an input field?

Tags: php, html, mysql, design-patterns, filter

for explanation i need this information for a project to handle Datamatrixcode - till this moment just everytime a number.

Okay i have a table with some numbers (unique_codes) and i take this numbers via SELECT these from a table (MySQL) and put them to an array ($row).

Scenario: the worker scans a number (and this numbers MUST BE a number from this $row list - then i $_POST this $row to other site to take it for the next step) otherwise i want a Error Exception.

My idea goes to us pattern like:

```
<form action="next site.php" method="post">
<input pattern="<?php $row['unique_code']; ?>"/>
<button class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
</form>
```

But this doesn´t work. 
How can i solve this? Try and catch as an alternativ ?

EDIT - with a solution:

I let the input field to that what a input form does: receive input.
So i $_POST a number to the second page and proof this to my values.

Comment: use single quote $row['unique_code'];

Comment: write down error corrected :)

Comment: am i solved your problem?

Comment: no, i has write it down wrong here but that code i still use is with singel quotes 'unique_code'

Answer (score 0):

I think you should either put `print` or `echo` in front of `$row['unique_code']` or replace `<?php` with `<?=`, but then you have to enable `short_open_tag` in php.ini

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have solved it in an other way - for information have a look to my edit at the top :D